# How to call TypeConverter.ConvertTo or ConvertToString with InvariantCulture but without implementing ITypeDescriptorContext

Tags: c#, .net, localization, tostring

In my convert method i get the wrong number separators when i use `TypeConverter.ConvertToString(Object)` because my system is in german. There is another overload for this method which looks like this: `TypeConverter.ConvertToString(ITypeDescriptorContext, CultureInfo, Object)`.

Is there a smart way to obtain the `ITypeDescriptorContext` or another option to call this method with `InvariantCulture` besides switching the culture before and after?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass `null` as a parameter

```
TypeConverter.ConvertToString(null, 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Object);
```